# Multiple Scanner objects crashing java program

Tags: java, string, while-loop

I am working on a project for a class and I keep running into a problem. I am trying to terminate a program when the user types stop. If I remove text = input.nextLine(); the code works correctly however it does not stop when the user request. I also tried making a new scanner object, but that did not fix the problem. Any help with this problem would be appreciated.
Thank you.

```
class blah
{     

 public static void main(String[] args)
{  
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String text = ("");

while(!text.equals("stop"))
  {
  System.out.print("Insert the number of items, holder value and passing value:");
  text = input.nextLine();
  int items = input.nextInt();
  int holder = input.nextInt();
  int passing = input.nextInt();
  killBot5000 josephus = new killBot5000(items,holder,passing);
  josephus.execute();
   } 
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the input can be either a String `stop` or three integers

You could change your code to just accept a line of input, decide if it is `stop` and if not then split the line into three tokens which can be converted to ints.

```
while(!text.equals("stop"))
{
  System.out.print("Insert the number of items, holder value and passing value:");
  text = input.nextLine();

  if (text.equalsIgnoreCase ("stop")) break;

  String arr [] = text.split (" ");
  int items = Integer.valueOf (arr[0]);
  int holder = Integer.valueOf (arr[1]);
  int passing =  Integer.valueOf (arr[2]);
  killBot5000 josephus = new killBot5000(items,holder,passing);
  josephus.execute();
}
```